# Android: Fetch changed data on server in real-time. Which technique is better?

Tags: android, location, parse-platform

I am building an app that shows user's friends' real-time locations on a map.
Each user updates his currnet location on the server (Parse.com) every defined interval (time and distance).
When a user opens the FindFriends activity, he'll get a map with markers on friends locations.
The friends locations data can be retrieved in two methods:

1. When activity is running, I am calling an AsyncTask that will download locations data from the server in a while loop (inside doInBackground), and after each time I call publishProgress() to handle the changes on the map.
2. I wrote a cloud code that is called every time a user updates his location on the server, which sends push notification to the relevant users (the user cant see the notification). When the FindFriends activity is running, a broadcast reciever is getting those pushes and update locations data on the map.

My question is: Which method is better for my needs or maybe I should do it differently? Of course I would like to keep battery consumption to minimum but not at expense of getting almost real time data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think that this is an appropriate question, since you really should just make a prototype using each implementation, and see which is more performant in your particular use case.  However, I can say that I definitely prefer the cloud solution. I've used [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) to implement a messaging client, and from my testing the updates are definitely really quick (very little noticeable lag time, when testing two clients side by side).  So, I don't think that implementing it with GCM would negatively impact your user experience, and it does have the plus side of eliminating pointless server polling when, potentially, no updates could be present - which saves on battery.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.
I've already implemented both ways and they're both work, but I dont know how it will response when there's a lot of users with a lot of relations. I have no idea what will happen when I'll send pushes to 100 users at once. and I cant see a way testing that before the release. 
So my question is what is the right way to implement such a feature.

Comment: Actually, in that case it's probably more appropriate to use GCM.  Refer to this link:  http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html, and the section on "Send Multicast Messages Efficiently"

Comment: Alright, I've realised that I should do it by pushes, but I am using Parse.com cloud and the Parse Push engine is handling the pushes. 
Does it matter? Should I switch to GCM?

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/2014/01/14/parse-push-adds-support-for-gcm/

Parse is now supporting GCM.

Thank you Submersed.
SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

If you want real time data then `push notification` GCM is not a good idea because, there is no guarantee that all users will get push notification in time. Sometime you will encounter delays in push notification.

Under given circumstances AsyncTask or Service can be a good way to perform required task, if they are handled properly. You should have control on AsyncTask/Service so that you can stop it any time you want.

Comment: So you suggest fetching all data and handle it in an AsyncTask or Service even if it means that I am getting unneccessary data?
Each user will have a lot of friends needed to be shown (probably more than 50), so I trying to find the most efficient way...

Comment: you backend show only send you data which is changed, means if you have 50 friends and location of 3 of them is changing then your back end should send you data of 3 friends not all